# Android, how to use only one instance of MediaPlayer in Widget

Tags: android, widget, media-player

Good day

I have a widget  and  I would like  to play and stop mp3 file  using my widget. I can play mp3 file but  I can't stop :(

Key moment - it's widget!
the reason of my problem - I don't know how to use only one instanse of media  player

Do you have any ideas?

here is my code

```
 public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
       RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
       Intent active = new Intent(context, HappyBabyWidget.class);
       active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
       PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
       remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonPlay, actionPendingIntent);
       appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.MyMusic);
      final String action = intent.getAction();

      if (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER.equals(action)) {
           if (mp.isPlaying())
               mp.stop(); 
            else
                mp.start();

       }
      super.onReceive(context, intent);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's a lot !
here is my final code

```
private static MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
      if (mp == null)
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.MyMusic);

      final String action = intent.getAction();

      if (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER.equals(action)) {
           if (mp.isPlaying())
           {
               mp.stop();
               mp.release();
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.MyMusic);

           }
            else
                mp.start();

       }
      super.onReceive(context, intent);
 }
}
          super.onReceive(context, intent);
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply don't declare your `MediaPlayer` locally in a method, and only initialize it if it is not already null:

```
 public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
  private MediaPlayer mp;

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
       RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
       Intent active = new Intent(context, HappyBabyWidget.class);
       active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
       PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
       remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonPlay, actionPendingIntent);
       appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
      if (mp == null)
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.MyMusic);
      final String action = intent.getAction();

      if (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER.equals(action)) {
           if (mp.isPlaying())
               mp.stop(); 
            else
                mp.start();

       }
      super.onReceive(context, intent);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you make your MediaPlayer variable static or you play your mp3 from a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). The latter seems to be the better solution.